Question about Young-Laplace equation proof
I was studying a proof of the Young-Laplace equation, but I came across a dubt in the very begin. Here the initial part of the proof:

Consider an interface separating two immiscible fluids that are in equilibrium with one another. Let these two fluids be denoted 1 and 2. Consider an arbitrary segment $S$ of this interface that is enclosed by some closed curve $ C$ . Let t denote a unit tangent to the curve, and let n denote a unit normal to the interface directed from fluid 1 to fluid 2. (Note that $C$ circulates around n in a right-handed manner. See Figure 3.1.) Suppose that $p_1$ and $p_2$ are the pressures of fluids 1 and 2, respectively, on either side of $S$ . Finally, let $\gamma$ be the (uniform) surface tension at the interface.


The net force acting on $ S$ is


$$ \vec{f}=\int_S (p_1-p_2)\vec{n}dS+\gamma \oint_C \vec{t} \times \vec{n} dr $$


where dS = ndS is an element of $S$ , and dr= tdr an element of $ C$ . Here, the first term on the right-hand side is the net normal force due to the pressure difference across the interface, whereas the second term is the net surface tension force. Note that body forces play no role in Equation (3.1), because the interface has zero volume.

Someone can explain why $\gamma \oint_C \vec{t} \times \vec{n} dr$ gives the surface tension force?
After that the proof continues in a clear manner.
Thanks for your attention!

The observed physical property of surface tension, as tension acting on  bodies in the interface, is that this is due to a set of forces that act on all elements of the body that are on the boundary between the body and the liquid (the body can be a piece of string, or a steel clip, or the liquid itself, like in the text you quote), and these forces are all in a direction that lies in the plane of the interface, but for each boundary element (in the quoted text, element of the curve $C$), it is perpendicular to it.
So $\vec{t}\times\vec{n}$ is there to give the infinitesimal force acting on the infinitesimal boundary element of length $dr$ the correct direction: vector $\vec{t}\times\vec{n}$  is obviously perpendicular to both $\vec{n}$ (thus it lies in the interface) and it is perpendicular to $\vec{t}$ (thus it is perpendicular to the body boundary element $dr \vec{t}$).

I got it, thank you! So, I would have another question: defining $\vec{F}=-\gamma (\vec{t} \times \vec{n})$, is it a vector that belongs to the tangent plane of the surface in a generic point P? I would say this is true, but I'm not completely sure.

@fede1602 Not sure why you've put a minus sign there, the quoted text does not have it. Also, that expression is force per unit length, $d\vec{F}/dr$. This force per unit length at any point of the interface P has direction that lies in the tangent plane to the interface at P, so when you draw an arrow, representing the force, as starting at P, the arrow lies in the tangent plane touching the interface at P.
